# Persistent shell arguments

Tags: bash, zsh, command-history

I often find myself running a series of commands on a single set of arguments.

For example:

```
$ nmap -Pn -sS 192.168.1.5
$ ssh 192.168.1.5
$ curl 192.168.1.5
$ wget -r 192.168.1.5
```

This can be sped up by putting the argument(s) in a variable,

```
$ a=192.168.1.5
$ nmap -Pn -sS $a
$ ssh $a
$ curl $a
$ wget -r $a
```

and sped up even more by using a couple of functions such as the following.

```
$ more .zshrc
...
paa() { PERSIST_ARGS+=("$@"); }
pa() { eval "$@" "${PERSIST_ARGS[@]}"; }
...
$ paa 192.168.1.5
$ pa nmap -Pn -sS
$ pa ssh
$ pa curl
$ pa wget -r
```

Is there a way to speed this up even more? For example,

```
$ <start special mode> 192.168.1.5
$ nmap -Pn -sS
$ ssh
$ curl
$ wget -r
$ <exit special mode>
```

I am looking for `bash` or `zsh` solutions. The solution has to work with an arbitrary set of commands.

Comment: For saving the command history inside shell scripts, you may want to look at the solution given here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5684/history-command-inside-bash-script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>Alt-_</kbd> already inserts the last word from the last command. For me, that's good enough, but you could add another key binding that inserts a space, that last word and accept the line (<kbd>Enter</kbd>).

With `tcsh` or `zsh` (for <kbd>Alt-S</kbd>, `S` for `same`):

```
bindkey -s '\es' ' \e_\r'
```

With `bash`:

```
bind '"\es": " \e_\r"'
```

Then type:

```
$ nmap -Pn -sS 192.168.1.5
$ ssh<Alt-S>
$ curl<Alt-S>
...
```

In `zsh` and `tcsh` at least, the *numerical argument* (that is when you prefix it with <kbd>Alt-<number></kbd>) will be applied to the space character which is not very useful (<kbd>Alt-3</kbd><kbd>Alt-S</kbd> would insert 3 spaces, the last word once and accept the line). It would be more useful to have it insert either the *n*<sup>th</sup> last word from the last command, or the last word from the *n*<sup>th</sup> last command, or the last *n* words from the last command.

In `zsh` at least, instead of using a macro, you could define a new widget. For instance with:

```
use-last-word() {
  LBUFFER+=" "
  zle insert-last-word
  zle accept-line
}

zle -N use-last-word
bindkey '\es' use-last-word
```

<kbd>Alt-3</kbd><kbd>Alt-S</kbd> would insert the 3<sup>rd</sup> last word from the last command.

To insert the last word from the 3<sup>rd</sup> last command:

```
use-last-word() { 
  LBUFFER+=" "
  local n=$NUMERIC
  unset NUMERIC
  repeat ${n:-1} zle insert-last-word
  zle accept-line
}
```

To insert the last 3 words from the last command:

```
use-last-word() { 
  for ((NUMERIC=${NUMERIC:-1}; NUMERIC; NUMERIC--)) {
    LBUFFER+=" "; zle insert-last-word
  }
  zle accept-line
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Although this doesn't work with multiple arguments, it works for most of my use cases.

Comment: @EvanTeitelman, see my edit for multiple arguments.

Answer (score 4):

I feel bad answering my own question like this, but I have a solution:

```
pst() {
    [ $# = 0 ] && return 1

    if [ -n $ZSH_VERSION ]; then
        local read=vared
    else
        local read=read
    fi

    local cmd
    local -a args
    args=("$@")
    while $read -p '> ' cmd ; do
        test -z "$cmd" && continue
        $cmd "${args[@]}"
    done
}
```

This works as such:

```
$ pst 192.168.1.5
> nmap -Pn -sS
> ssh
> curl
> wget -r
```

I'm going to leave the question open for a little while to see if any superior solutions show up. One major downside of this solution is that the commands it runs are not logged.

Comment: Like your answer.  I must have missed some part in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I've not implemented anything like this but I wonder if you could tap into the 2 facilities offered by the shell. The $PATH and the command complete.

When you're in your "special mode" you could provide something like the tab complete but instead of having to repeatedly hit it, you type a few letters of the actual command you want to run nm (for nmap) and hit a key combo similar to tab which would then interrogate the $PATH looking for executables that match what you've typed so far and then return a list to you like so:

I type:

```
$ pst 192.168.1.5
> nm <press SHIFT-TAB>
```

I'm offered the following list back:

```
1* - nmap 192.168.1.5    2 - nmap2 192.168.1.5    3 - nmap3 192.168.1.5
```

**NOTE:** The above list would be what matched what I typed from interrogating the `$PATH`.

From the list above I could either hit enter to accept the first response (1*), or type the number of the match that I want to use:

```
>> 2 <press ENTER>
```

You could also integrate the `complete` facility in bash and other shells to narrow down the matches so that only matches that can accept the types of arguments provided to `pst <arg>` would be considered in the match.