# Some commands not working when executed via ssh while redirecting output locally

Tags: bash, ssh, command-history

I can run the following two commands for example and get the output locally:

```
ssh user@remote.ip ls > testhistory.txt  
ssh user@remote.ip "cat .bash_history" > testhistory.txt
```

But if I run the following command, the local output is always empty:

```
ssh user@remote.ip history > testhistory.txt
```

If I `ssh` to the remote destination and then run the `history` command, i get the expected output.

Why does the `history` command not output results when run inline with `ssh` but the `ls` command works normally? What do i need to change to make the `history` command output results to local file the way I did the `ls` command without having to `cat` the `.bash_history` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`history` is an internal command to bash, so you don't want to run the executable `history`, you want to run the executable `bash`. `ls` works because is an executable on its own, usually at `/bin/ls`.

Besides that, by default bash disables the history in non-interactive shells, as is the case when you run a remote command.

You can create a shell script in the remote machine to enable it and run history, example:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
HISTFILE=~/.bash_history
set -o history
history
```

Or, if you really want to do all that from the ssh call, you can do:

```
ssh user@remote.ip 'echo -e "HISTFILE=~/.bash_history\nset -o history\nhistory" | bash'
```

Note that it also doesn't take into account the `HISTTIMEFORMAT` variable, if you use it in the remote machine, so plan for that.

References: [History command inside bash script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5684/history-command-inside-bash-script)

Comment: what would a working command look like?  `ssh user@remote.ip "bash history" > testhistory.txt` doesn't work

Comment: `ssh` with additional non-option arguments passes them to the remote shell (all as one `-c`) so builtins DO work (try `ssh u@h declare -p`); noninteractive -> disable history is the only issue. And you don't need the remote shell to run yet another, just `ssh u@h 'HISTFILE=~/.bash_history; set -o history; history'` -- or even quote only the semicolons: `ssh u@h HISTFILE=~/.bash_history';'set -o history';'history` but that looks really odd

Comment: Is there a way to make all variables enabled or find out what's disabled when in non-interactive shell?