# How to have bash' history as the same as the preceding Bash'?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, command-history

How to have bash' history as the same as the preceding Bash'?

Few last history of bash is demanded to be so in the following but fail

```
$ bash -lc 'find . -iname \*.c;  bash -l'
#or

$ bash -lc 'history -s find . -iname \*.c; history -w; bash -l'
```

won't have history of

```
find . -iname \*.c
```

How to solve such this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are invoking a non-interactive shell to run your `find`-command.

Non-interactive shells do not have history by default.

See [History command inside bash script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5684/history-command-inside-bash-script) for possible solutions.