# Why doesn't history output anything in a subshell?

Tags: bash, command-history

I just realized that `history` does not output anything in a subshell. I'll try to show by counting lines - first a sanity check with echo:

```bsh
$ echo a | wc -l
1
```

... and in a subshell:

```bsh
bash -c 'echo a' | wc -l
1
```

Indeed, we expect one line output in both cases. Now, for `history`:

```bsh
$ history | wc -l
681
```

... but in a subshell:

```bsh
$ bash -c 'history' | wc -l
0
```

... `history` returns no lines.

Why does this happen - and how can I get the `history` in the subshell to output the history of the current shell (including last session commands)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`-c` doesn't create a *subshell*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/261661/108618); it just creates a non-interactive new shell (or rather, a non-interactive execution environment in a separate process that has nothing to do with your current shell). And: in non-interactive shells, the `history` command is intentionally non-functional:

[History command inside bash script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5684/history-command-inside-bash-script)